# Liferay 5.2.3 Asset publisher portlet : Close link remove for particular user

Tags: liferay, assets, publisher

I am new in liferay. In new page i have added asset publisher porlet.
There is Look and Feel , Configuration and Close link.

I want to remove Close link for particular user.

Liferay version : 5.2.3

plz anyone help me...

Comment: You probably need to add version-specific tags to your question (e.g. [tag:liferay-7]).

Comment: do you want to remove only close link or every option ?
check configuration

Comment: only close link @ parth Ghiya

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Liferay Web content Display Portlet : Look and Feel - Portlet Configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41999913/liferay-web-content-display-portlet-look-and-feel-portlet-configuration)