# Liferay Web content Display Portlet : Look and Feel - Portlet Configuration

Tags: liferay

After adding web content display portlet , click on Look and Feel - Portlet Configuration - Show Borders.

If i uncheck Show Borders, it display three links as per below screenshot
[image]

Can anyone tell this three links code contains in which file?

I want to remove close link only from all the portlet

Comment: You can manage to show configuration option to specific roles only.

Comment: Agree with @ParkashKumar. It should be handled by roles permissions rather code.

Comment: Please go for the source code to check,what all Roles are checked for this section and only in case when you want to update only a certain setting,rather than whole section,should you look for code options

Answer (score 0):

Those portlet options come from below files:

`portal-web\docroot\html\themes\_unstyled\templates\portlet.vm`
portlet.vm uses `$theme.portletIconOptions()` to include different options (configuration, close, Maximize, Minimize etc)

`util-taglib\src\com\liferay\taglib\util\VelocityTaglibImpl.java`

Implementation of portletIconOptions method is in this class which uses IconOptionsTag - custom tag.

`util-taglib\src\com\liferay\taglib\portletext\IconOptionsTag.java`

And this in-turn uses different custom tags for each of the options.

`portal-web\docroot\html\taglib\portlet\icon_options\page.jsp`

```
<liferay-portlet:icon-portlet-css />

<liferay-portlet:icon-configuration />

<liferay-portlet:icon-edit />

<liferay-portlet:icon-edit-defaults />

<liferay-portlet:icon-edit-guest />

<liferay-portlet:icon-export-import />

<liferay-portlet:icon-help />

<liferay-portlet:icon-print />

<liferay-portlet:icon-maximize />

<liferay-portlet:icon-minimize />

<liferay-portlet:icon-close />
```

`